# How can I access the API static via basic auth to a Kubernetes cluster on GCE

Tags: kubernetes

I know it's possible to access the static views of the api, but I can't find out the basic auth details that I need to login via the browser. Where can I find these? I'm on GCE and created a cluster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `kubectl config view`. It'll dump out the auth information used to access your cluster, including the basic auth username and password.